# Why are the subviews out of the bounds of my custom View not drawn?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I implement a custom `SpinNumberView`: it is square shaped (say 40x40), it has a vertical `LinearLayout` as a subview, within this linear layout are a bunch of 40x40 cells stacked vertically. I want to animate the cells to scroll vertically by changing offsetY of the `LinearLayout`.

But there is one problem: only the cell initially in bounds (the first) is rendered, the cells outside of the bounds are not drawn, so when I animate the LinearLayout to scroll, the linear layout is spinning, but only the first cell is visible, others are blank spaces. Here is my entire code for the custom View:

```
public class SpinNumberView extends RelativeLayout {
private int startNumber;
private int endNumber;
private int number;
private int gridsize;
private int index;
public static final double stepDuration = 0.1;

private boolean inAnimation = true;
ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
public LinearLayout container;

public SpinNumberView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SpinNumberView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw the background black solid circle
    float radius = (float)(this.gridsize);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setARGB(192, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawCircle(radius/2, radius/2, radius/2, p);
    // draw 1px white border
    Paint pp = new Paint();
    pp.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    pp.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    pp.setARGB(192, 255, 255, 255);
    canvas.drawCircle(radius/2, radius/2, radius/2-1, pp);
    // clip to the circle
    Path path = new Path();
    RectF r = new RectF((float)0.0, (float)0.0, radius, radius);
    path.addRoundRect(r, radius/2, radius/2, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    super.onLayout(b, i, i1, i2, i3);
}

class AniListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        SpinNumberView.this.animateStep();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {}
}

public void animateStep() {
    this.container.setTranslationY(0);

    float offset;
    TimeInterpolator inter;

    if(this.inAnimation) {
        offset = (float)this.gridsize * this.numbers.size();
        inter = new LinearInterpolator();
    } else {
        offset = (float)this.gridsize * this.index;
        inter = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    }
    long duration = (long)(SpinNumberView.stepDuration * this.numbers.size() * 1000);

    ViewPropertyAnimator ani = this.container.animate().translationYBy(-offset).setDuration(duration);
    ani.setInterpolator(inter);
    if(this.inAnimation) {
        ani.setListener(new AniListener());
    } else {
        ani.setListener(null);
    }
    ani.start();
}

public void stopAnimation() {
    this.inAnimation = false;
}

public void startAnimation() {
    this.inAnimation = true;
    float offset = (float)this.gridsize * this.numbers.size();
    long duration = (long)(SpinNumberView.stepDuration * this.numbers.size() * 1000);
    ViewPropertyAnimator ani = this.container.animate().translationYBy(-offset).setDuration(duration);
    TimeInterpolator inter = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    ani.setInterpolator(inter);
    ani.setListener(new AniListener());
    ani.start();
}

public void setup(int number, int start, int end, int gridsize) {
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    this.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
    this.setClipChildren(false);

    this.number = number;
    this.startNumber = start;
    this.endNumber = end;
    this.gridsize = gridsize;
    this.numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=start; i<=end;i++) {
        this.numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(this.numbers);
    // Find index of target number within shuffled array
    this.index = this.numbers.indexOf(this.number);

    this.container = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
    this.container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    this.container.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.gridsize, this.gridsize * (this.numbers.size()+1));
    this.container.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.addView(this.container);

    int offsety = 0;
    // setup all the number views
    for(int k=0;k<this.numbers.size()+1;k++) {
        String txt;
        if(k==this.numbers.size()) {
            txt = Integer.toString(this.numbers.get(0));
        } else {
            txt = Integer.toString(this.numbers.get(k));
        }

        TextView tv = new TextView(this.getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(this.gridsize, this.gridsize));
        tv.setText(txt);
        tv.setTextSize(24.0f);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tv.setLines(1);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        this.container.addView(tv);

        offsety += this.gridsize;
    }

    this.invalidate();
}
}
```

Why is this happening?

BTW: I take a screenshot with `getDrawingCache()` of screen content, the cells are visible in the screenshot!

Comment: have you tried using LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: @AmitVaghela Yes, tried that.

Comment: Have you tried using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`? Use the `LayoutParams` subclass specific to the container.

Comment: did you override `onLayout` / `onMeasure` in your custom `ViewGroup`?

Comment: @pskink I override onLayout but forgot to call super.onLayout()... But when I do, the subviews out of bounds are not drawn. Why?

Comment: then post the source code of your container view

Comment: @pskink Code posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

When overriding `onLayout()` function, I need to layout the subviews myself like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
    super.onLayout(b, i, i1, i2, i3);
    this.container.layout(0, 0, this.gridsize, this.gridsize * (this.endNumber-this.startNumber+2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It happend when we get some view `height` or `width` of a view. Because didn't completely render the view when we call its `height` or `width` yet.

**Solution:**

Use this code to get Height and width

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewbyid(R.id.tv);

edt.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int height= edt.getHeight();
                int width = edt.getHeight();
                edt.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved it by yourself, in iOS, we use something like Redraw method for these scenarios. Hopefully it will help you to further optimize your code.